# Como acessar conteudo de um arquivo json?

Tags: python, twitter-api

Possuo um arquivo JSON de informações extraídas do Twitter através da biblioteca `tweepy`, um pedaço do conteúdo do arquivo é o seguinte:

```
Status(extended_entities={'media': [{'source_user_id': 3383675067, 'url': 'https://t.co/x03h8R996T', 'media_url_https': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPkZCyZX0AAB6QP.jpg', 'type': 'photo', 'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/x03h8R996T', 'source_status_id': 934805944525099008, 'id': 934805933334712320, 'indices': [100, 123], 'id_str': '934805933334712320', 'media_url': 'http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPkZCyZX0AAB6QP.jpg', 'sizes': {'small': {'w': 512, 'h': 288, 'resize': 'fit'},....
```

O conteúdo fica todo dentro deste método `Status`

Como posso pegar alguns conteúdo dentro deste arquivo, por exemplo, `"'id_str': '934805933334712320'"`?

Comment: Por favor, coloque seu código na pergunta para vermos como está fazendo. Isso que nos apresentou não é um JSON, então provavelmente você está interpretando alguma coisa de forma equivocada.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consegues aceder ao conteúdo do arquivo?

Se conseguires, não é muito complicado. Posso estar a ver mal, parece-me que é um dicionário e a key `media` tem como valor uma lista. Sendo assim, acedes ao 1º elemento (não vejo mais nenhum elemento) e esse primeiro elemento é um dicionário, por isso basta acederes pelo nome da key. Acho que o resultado final seria este:

```
extended_entities['media'][0]['id_str']
```

Answer (score 1):

O arquivo está retornando um arquivo em JSON que precisa ser interpretado.

```
 import json
 j = json.loads('{"id_str": "934805933334712320", "media_url": "http://pbs.twimg.com/media/DPkZCyZX0AAB6QP.jpg"}')

 print j['id_str']
```

Comment: E o resto do json ? Porque no seu exemplo só tem a parte que começa em `id_str` ?